# Remove certain characters from char*

Tags: string, array, pointer

I've got an array of char* with serial data that I'm trying to remove ':' from. I have tried to iterate through the char*, find and remove any colons but it just comes out as garbage.

```c
  char* espData[15];

  // pull data from serial and tokenize with strtok > feed to espData

  for(int x = 0; x < index-1; x++){
    size_t nullTerm = strlen(espData[x]);
    espData[x][nullTerm - 1] = '\0';
    char* output
    for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(espData[x]); ++i){
      if(espData[x][i] != ':') output += espData[x][i];
    }
    espData[x] = output;
    Serial.println(espData[x]);
  }
```

Moving the null character works fine (I wanted to get rid of the last character in every string). Most of the answers I found for general C++ used std::string which we don't have access to.

Comment: Arithmetic on a `char*` does nothing to its contents.

Comment: the comment `tokenize with strtok` suggests your code uses strtok, which would be one (probably bloated) solution - yet your code doesn't use strtok!!?

Comment: `espData[x][nullTerm - 1] = '\0';` is redundant code

Comment: @Jaromanda Actually, it overwrites the last character in the string - or underflows the buffer if `nullTerm` is `0`!

Comment: @JohnBurger - of course you're right

Comment: @JaromandaX the comment is just placeholder for code that I already had working correctly with strtok so I left it out for brevity.

Comment: @JohnBurger I hadn't thought of underflow on the buffer, I will put it a check for that. Do you know what kind of problems that could cause if it did underflow?

Comment: @Tri42 **Shudder!** I _don't_ want to think about it! It depends on where you got `espData[x]` from: the heap? You're going to trash the previous object on the heap. The stack? You've going to corrupt another variable - or worse, the return address from a function. The data section? You're simply going to alter an unintended variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've assumed that a `char *` is some kind of string object, since you've got the following line of code: `output += espData[x][i];`, and then later `espData[x] = output;`

It quite simply doesn't work like that. At best you can point `output` inside `espData[x]` and then do some other logic: but your attempt to "accumulate" the correct characters is incorrect.

Please consider the following code instead:

```
char* espData[15];

for(int x = 0; x < index-1; x++){
    size_t nullTerm = strlen(espData[x]); // Get current length
    char* output = espData[x];            // Start of string
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nullTerm; ++i){
        if(espData[x][i] != ':') {        // If it's NOT a colon
            *output++ = espData[x][i];    // Copy character 'up'
        } // if
                                          // If it WAS a colon, then
                                          // output does NOT get incremented
    } // for
    *output = '\0'; // End string off with NUL
    Serial.println(espData[x]);
} // for
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! I have never been great with pointers

Comment: @Tri42 I just finished a pointer-post on another question. Take a look: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/25317/22924